# How to include javascript in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I can not connect an external JavaScript file to my html page.
When I put the script in the page with the  tag it all works
but when I insert it in an external file is not working, what is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE!>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- JQuery da Google -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---------------------->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Document</title>
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- JS-->
<script src="js/function.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<footer>
<img class="info" src="img/newsletter.png" width="32" height="32" alt="info" />
</footer>

<div id="info">
    <ul class="infomenu">
        <li class="newsletter">NEWSLETTER</li>
        <li>PRIVACY</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
        <li>FOLLOW US</li>
    </ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
    //Jquery Info
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".info").hover(function(){
        $("#info").fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $(".close").click(function(){
        $("#info").fadeOut("slow");
    });

});
```

Comment: Correct your doctype first. Where is the <html> tag? :)

Comment: @ManojKumar — The `<html>` tag is optional.

Comment: Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/)

Comment: Also, why are you using jQuery 1.3.2?  That is a very old version.

Comment: is your path correct?

Comment: @Quentin Oh I see. Even when using a closing `</html>` at the bottom? It is not picked up by the browser?

Comment: Are you sur your `js/function.js` is the right path to your file ?

Comment: I suspect the path to your JavaScript file is incorrect try `/js/function.js`

Comment: "<!DOCTYPE!>" should be "<!DOCTYPE html>"

Comment: script tag do not have a language attribute, has it ?

Comment: @MiguelSR — Yes. The start tag is optional. The end tag is optional. The optionalness is independant.

Comment: Are you running the html file directly in a browser or via localhost?

Comment: The code "works" when it run it. Obviously I can't hover the image to fade in the content until I've added something with the close class so I can fade it out in the first place. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @SwarajGiri — That shouldn't matter. The code doesn't do anything that behaves differently on a file: scheme URI.

Comment: Have you include the Jquery library

Comment: @TharakaArachchige — It's on line 5 of the code in the question!

Comment: You seem new to all this so I'll ask a basic question - did you create a folder called "js" within the directory where your file is, which then includes the `function.js` file?

Comment: Your code works buddy.. you just need to hide `#info` first so that it can be faded in.. ;)

Comment: @Quentin - Putting it in external file breaks js, sounded like a possible url rewrite. No?

Comment: @SwarajGiri — There are some much simpler *wrong URL* explanations than URL rewriting. Typos and not understanding how relative paths work are much more common.

Comment: @ManojKumar I changed the doctype and I added html tags and now works, was so simple .. Thank you all!

Comment: Path was correct and css too, was just a doctype and html tag problem

Answer (score 5):

You really messed up your html code, try googling for the HTML(5) basics, first of you should learn the basic construction of it like following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="styles/default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- HTML Content -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src=".."></script>
        <script>
        // Javascript inside this file
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `link`- and `script` part is not necessary, but you mostly will need it so I put it in the right order in.
Try putting `script`-Tags over the closing `</body>`-Tag, this will prevent that the page is loading endless for the Javascript file, before the page is actually loaded.

This way the external Javascript should work, also if you working localy, you should use a Webserver software like XAMPP. If you use XAMPP, after installing it, you have to start the `Apache Service` and then you work inside (if you didn't changed the path) the `C:\xampp\htdocs` folder. If you create a folder inside it called `testing` and place your `index.php` inside it, you just can type following in the browser `http://localhost/testing` and it will search for a index. html or php file and parse it.

If you just double click the file, you mostly will end up with security issues, which will prevent your code will work like you intended to do. You know that you double clicked a file if it starts like `file://` and not `http://`.

But like I said, google for tutorials from the scratch. It takes time, but you can't do it without taking the time. Trust me, I do this for over 7 Years now and I am online nearly everyday and learning, learning, reading, testing, coding, learning, reading, testing and I STILL think that this is less than 5% of knowledge what I could learn.. never think you are at the end or near to it.. you never are, there are always things to learn and if you keep in thought that you are near the end, you will stop improving and never become good.

Comment: Giving downvotes without an explain is like saying "Coffee is bad.". At this point the question is:"Why is coffee bad? Do you don't like the taste? Do you think the coffein is bad? Because it paints your teeth brown? But what about positiv effects of coffein and coffee in general?". Be constructive, don't use that button just to gain badges, that's lame, unproductive and doesn't provide quality! If you think I didn't answered, then: I  did. Read again, understand it. If you can't manage the basics, your code won't work and that's part of it. I showed and explained the steps.

Comment: Was probably the other answer who is just jealous/jaded that he got downvoted so lashing out.   I see a lot of revenge voting on here.  I'll shoot you an upvote to help out :)

Comment: @NotoriousPet0 Could be, but he has not enough points to downvote. I also catched myself in thoughts about doing that, but I deleted every thoughts of that.. but other people could actually do this.. I would expect that from some people, because people are people, right? I mean if there is something wrong, CORRECT ME. I want to learn more and more, but I can't learn anything from a downvote. I don't know if there is really something wrong or just jealoussy or maybe he didn't like my english or I forgot a `,` (comma) anywhere and he is like "downvote!". Critic is good, but with an explain, pls!

Comment: I agree, I just posted a huge bold note on my latest question asking people to please explain why they are downvoting.  Its very frustrating when the first vote takes you to -1 and then everyone has a bad first impression of yoru question, I'm sure a lot of them just downvote because others did.  It just snowballs.    Downvote should require a comment ... maybe I'll post that on meta.   At least a downvote only -2 and upvote +10 right?  :)

Comment: "Downvote should require a comment", this is a pretty good idea! Maybe at least the first 2-3 downvotes or the comment section will blow up with the same explain multible times. The snowball effect is real, a "-1" leads heavy to continue that way without actually reading and understanding the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".info").hover(function(){
        $("#info").fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $(".close").click(function(){
        $("#info").fadeOut("slow");
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful

Comment: It's kinda self explanatory... 
I would have thought he would at least have some knowledge about JS before jumping head first into it!
`<script></script>` tags represent for JS/JQuery to go inside etc. Same as `<?php ?>`